# git pull all prefix in subtrees

Tags: git, git-subtree, gitlab-ce

I want to do a `git pull subtree --prefix local/path http://mygitlab.domain/user/repo.git master --squash`. but I have multiple subtrees, I want to update all subtrees at once, but I can't find a reference to do that.

the way I do it now, update one by one subtrees then I push it to the main repository, but that method is less effective. I've also created an automatic script but I don't think it's reliable, because if I deploy on a different machine I have to adjust the script.

Comment: so that means `git pull subtree=<path>` is a no-go

Comment: @DaemonPainter it only works for 1 path 1 subtree

Comment: you can call it multiple times in your script

Comment: @DaemonPainter yeah right, the method I am currently using is like that, but I think there is a more reliable way without adding a bash script